# Getting type error in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am getting the following error while trying to split a photo url which is fetched from DB.

Error:

```
TypeError (wrong argument type Fixnum (expected Regexp)):
```

Please check my below line of code.

```
  @sdf=TSdf.find_by_Receipt_No(params[:sdf][:Receipt_No])
        # output of @sdf.photo=C:\Swargadwara_Puri\SDF\2015-05-03_05-04-07-PM_DECEASED_150503012.jpg
        @b_photo=@sdf.Photo
        @b_photos=@b_photo.split(23)
```

Here i need only `@b_photos=2015-05-03_05-04-07-PM_DECEASED_150503012.jpg` Please help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1):

[`String#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-split) splits the string into array by pattern:

```
@b_photos = @b_photo.split(File::SEPARATOR).last
```

Here we split the string into array by [`File::SEPARATOR`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/File.html#SEPARATOR), containing parts of path and choose the very last item, which is apparently the file name.

Whether the path may come from both windows and unix environments, the separator may differ:

```
@b_photos = @b_photo.split(/[\/\\]/).last
```

Comment: @ mudasobwa : Can you say here how can i get @b_photos=2015-05-03_05-04-07-PM_DECEASED_150503012.jpg by using your instruction.

Comment: The expression above will give you `2015-05-03_05-04-07-PM_DECEASED_150503012.jpg`. See update.

Comment: @ mudasobwa : No,I checked its giving the whole path.

Comment: See an update. You could mention at least that you are running unix.